# Nested field resolvers in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, nestjs, code-first

The goal is to use NestJS to implement a GraphQL schema using the code-first approach.

Let's say I have a `Pet` type in my GraphQL schema with two fields, `name` and `age`. If those two pieces of information come from different sources of truth (and I don't always want to fetch both), I could implement a `PetResolver` class with resolvers for each field:

```
@Resolver(() => Pet)
export class PetResolver {
  @Query(() => Pet)
  pet(): Pet {
    return {};
  }

  @ResolveField()
  name(): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve('Spot');
  }

  @ResolveField(() => Int)
  age(): Promise<number> {
    return Promise.resolve(2);
  }
}
```

which could be used like this:

```
query GetPet {
  pet {
    name
  }
}
```

This works and would ensure that the value of each field is only fetched when requested, but what if I wanted to have a `pet` field on my `User` type that I could query like this:

```
query GetUserWithPet {
  currentUser {
    email
    pet {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Applying the same principle, I could create a UserResolver class like this:

```
@Resolver(() => User)
export class UserResolver {
  @Query(() => User)
  @UseGuards(AuthCognitoGuard)
  currentUser(@CurrentUser() user: IdTokenPayload): User {
    return {
      id: user.sub,
      email: user.email,
    };
  }

  @ResolveField()
  pet(@Parent() user: User): Promise<Pet> {
    return petService.getPetForUserId(user.id);
  }
}
```

but then the `PetService` implementation would have to be aware of which fields were requested if it only wanted to fetch relevant data.

A) Is there a way to use `PetResolver` within `UserResolver` to make use of the individual field resolution logic?

B) If not, what is the best way to determine which fields were requested in the query using NestJS code-first conventions?

C) Is this the "wrong" way to think about GraphQL queries? Do best practices dictate that I keep the separate resolver and use a query like this:

```
query GetUserWithPet {
  currentUser {
    email
  }
  pet {
    name
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

User should contain some `petIds` [array] value (internal, DB stored field/column) ...

... making possible to resolve `pets: [Pet]` prop/relation - list of `Pet` ...

... like `starshipIDs` explained in https://graphql.org/learn/execution/

**Notice**: pets service is asked about records using pet ids.

... but of course pet can contain some `ownerId` (only or explicitely visible, DB stored field/column) making possible to resolve `owner: User` prop [reverse] relation - this way you can:

```
query PetWithOwner {
  pet (id: "someID") {
    id
    name
    owner {
      id
      email
      # more pets?
      pets {
        id
        name
        # you can loop it ;)
        owner {
          id
          email
```

`pet.owner` field resolver can return only `{ id: ownerId }` object (partial response) ... server will try to resolve 'missing' (required by query) `email` prop using `User` (`owner` is `User` type) type resolver, passing id as an arg (check/console.log `parent` and `args` resolver args). You don't have to do it [the same] 'manually' inside `pet.owner` field resolver.

### Query required fields ...

... [selection set] can be read from `info` object - 4th resolver arg - read docs/tutorial for details

Comment: Where is the Node-JS code first approach?  This doesn't fully answer the question